# Scala match in equals method

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, equals

I'm new to Scala, but have a decent Java background. My question is about overriding the equals method in Scala. The following example is from the Scala cookbook:

```
class Person (name: String, age: Int) {
    def canEqual(a: Any) = a.isInstanceOf[Person]
    override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
        that match {
            case that: Person => that.canEqual(this) && this.hashCode == that.hashCode
            case _ => false
     }
}
```

My question is why we need

```
that.canEqual(this)
```

My understanding is that that code will only be executed if 'that' is a person. So, why the extra call to isInstanceOf?

Comment: From Scala Cookbook? This equals doesn't work, specifically the `this.hashCode == that.hashCode`, two objects of the same class can have can the same hashCode and be different.

Comment: @pedrofurla Depends on your definition of "work". The definition of `equals` is up to the discretion of the programmer. The only requirements are that it be reflexive, symmetric, transitive, consistent, and that it return false for null.

Comment: Yeah, I know that this equals method doesn't work. This is more about understanding the scala syntax

Comment: Two different strings can have the same hashCode, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`that.canEqual(this)` is not redundant. It is necessary in case `that` is an instance of a subclass of `Person` that has defined it's own equality (and it's own `canEqual` method).

`this.canEqual(that)` on the other hand would be redundant.

The main purpose is to ensure that the equality relation is valid **in both directions** between an instance of `Person` and potentially a subclass of `Person` that may have it's own implementation of equals.

Suppose I have:

```
 class Person(...) {
    ... as defined, but without the `that.canEqual(this)` call
 }

 class Nobody extends Person {
   // contrived, but valid definition
   override def equals (that: Any) = false 
   ... and some definition of hashCode that happens to produce same value
 }

 ...
 // then
 new Person(...) == new Nobody // true
 new Nobody == new Person(...) // false

 // breaks equals by not being symmetric
```

More detailed explanation link provided by pedrofurla in the comments: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html

Comment: `isInstanceOf[Person]` is true to anything that extends Person, regardless of having or not overridden the equals method.

Comment: @pedrofurla The key is this part `that.canEqual(this)`. See: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/8379

Comment: But that.canEqual(this) is just a call to isInstanceOf. I honestly don't see the point of even defining canEqual when you can just use isInstanceOf directly.

Comment: @alexgbelov Not quite. `that.canEqual(this)` could potentially be a call to an overridden `canEquals` on the subclass. It's not necessarily a call to `isInstanceOf`

Comment: The explanation is here http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html. It's an overridable "isInstance"-like check.

Answer (score 0):

Two different objects from two separate classes can have the same hash code; you therefore cannot say that two objects are equal based on their hash code alone. For example, a `Dog` with yellow fur and a loud bark might have `hashCode` of 20011 because of the way a `Dog` defines `hashCode`; a `RocketShip` designed to fly to Saturn might also have a `hashCode` of 20011 for a very unrelated reason. Clearly, these are two very different objects. If, however, two `Dogs` or two `RocketShips` have the same hash code then it is probably* safe to assume they're equivalent objects: it wouldn't make any sense to have to have two equivalent objects (e.g., two `Dogs` with yellow fur and loud barks) have two different hash codes, and it wouldn't make sense to have two different objects of the same type (e.g., one `Dog` with black fur, another with brown fur) have the same hash code. The `isInstanceOf` check lets you ensure that you're dealing with two objects of the same type: the hash code check allows you to quickly assess whether or not two objects *should* be equivalent.

(*: If there are a finite number of hash codes and an infinite combination of attributes producing unique `Dogs`, then there will inevitably be hash code collisions. Even the `isInstanceOf` check isn't sufficient, but is probably good enough for most cases and hence in the cookbook as an example.)

**Edit:** See [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html):

> Pitfall #2: Changing equals without also changing hashCode.
>   If two objects are equal according to the equals method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result

In short, two equal objects must have the same hash code to fulfill the method's contract (but nowhere does it say that two objects with equal hash codes must be equal!)

**Edit 2**
As you have a Java background, you're likely used to seeing something of the following.

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {

   // I am a Dog. If they're not a dog, I can't be equal to them.
   if (!(other instanceof Dog)) 
      return false;

   // If the other dog's properties are equal to my own, then we're equal.
   if (...)
      return true;
   // If not, we're not equal.
   else
      return false;
 }
```

The code sample you've given is doing (roughly) the same thing, with the `hashCode` check substituting for an equality check.

Comment: The `isInstanceOf` check *is* necessary.

Comment: Yes, but not sufficient. I haven't disagreed with you in my answer. :)

Comment: My question is about the line `case that: Person`. As far as I can tell, that line checks if `that` is a person, and if that is true, then it does the rest of the comparison logic. If I'm in that block, then I know that `that` is a person, so the instanceOf check is redundant

Comment: Ahhhh, my apologies -- I misunderstood! See Alvaro's answer noting that it's needed to ensure that "equality relation is valid in both directions."